# Webservice fetching different results while deployed, but in local dev, it shows full results

Tags: .net, web-services

I am facing a weird problem.
When i run a web service on local host, i am able to fetch all the results as per required. but, when i deploy the same in IIS server, it does not fetch full results. I tried deploying new site but did not help . Any ideas?

Comment: No details, no answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was'nt in the coding part, as suggested.

Changes in **Access rights** for the site did resolve the issue.(Security access rights in properties of the application folder)

In visual studio, it fetches all of the access rights for the developer mode, but when deployed, it requires special permission for the folder to access(like NETWORK Service and so on)

Thanks